# Kofax KTM Validation Routing

Tags: vba, kofax

I'm working on a Kofax KTM project, that have multiple Validation steps.
After the KTM Server Module the batch will be routed to another validation step depending on the Batch name.

Now the routing works well, but if its not the first validation step the following error occurs:

[image: Validation Message]

Anyone an idea how to fix this?
thx

Here is my code:

```
' Rout Document to the Correct Validation step.
Private Sub Batch_Close(ByVal pXRootFolder As CASCADELib.CscXFolder, ByVal CloseMode As 
CASCADELib.CscBatchCloseMode)
   Dim i As Long
   Dim mandat As String
   Dim lVal As Long
   Dim strVal As String
   Dim oXDocInfo As CASCADELib.CscXDocInfo
   Dim folder As CASCADELib.CscXFolder

   ' only enter after extraction and after validation
If CloseMode = CASCADELib.CscBatchCloseFinal Then
  If Project.ScriptExecutionMode = CscScriptModeServer Or Project.ScriptExecutionMode = CscScriptModeValidation Then
           ' get root folder
     Set folder = pXRootFolder
     While Not folder.IsRootFolder
        Set folder = folder.ParentFolder
     Wend

     ' get batch name
     mandat = folder.XValues.ItemByName("AC_BATCH_CLASS_NAME").Value
     lVal = 0
     strVal = ""

     Select Case mandat
        Case "x"
           lVal = 0
        Case "y"
           lVal = 2
     End Select

     strVal = CStr(lVal)

     If Project.ScriptExecutionMode = CscScriptModeValidation Then
        For i = 0 To folder.GetTotalDocumentCount - 1
           Set oXDocInfo = folder.GetDocInfoByGlobalIndex(i)
           oXDocInfo.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING", strVal)
        Next
        folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "kfxpdf.exe")
     ElseIf Project.ScriptExecutionMode = CscScriptModeServer Then
        For i = 0 To folder.GetTotalDocumentCount - 1
           Set oXDocInfo = folder.GetDocInfoByGlobalIndex(i)
           oXDocInfo.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING", strVal)
           oXDocInfo.XDocument.NextValidationInstance = lVal
        Next
        ' validation is not done => rout to the depending validation instance
        If(lVal = 0) Then
           folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "KTM.Validation")
        Else
           folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DCOUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "KTM.Validation")
           folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "KTM.Validation" & strVal)
           pXRootFolder.Valid = False
        End If
     End If
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

The value of `KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_` must not be the same like the next validation instance...

so thats the code that works:

```
Private Sub Batch_Close(ByVal pXRootFolder As CASCADELib.CscXFolder, ByVal CloseMode As CASCADELib.CscBatchCloseMode)
Dim i As Long
Dim mandat As String
Dim lVal As Long
Dim strVal As String
Dim oXDocInfo As CASCADELib.CscXDocInfo
Dim folder As CASCADELib.CscXFolder

' only enter after extraction and after validation
If CloseMode = CASCADELib.CscBatchCloseFinal Then
  If Project.ScriptExecutionMode = CscScriptModeServer Or Project.ScriptExecutionMode = CscScriptModeValidation Then
           ' get root folder
     Set folder = pXRootFolder
     While Not folder.IsRootFolder
        Set folder = folder.ParentFolder
     Wend

     ' get batch name
     mandat = folder.XValues.ItemByName("AC_BATCH_CLASS_NAME").Value
     lVal = 0
     strVal = ""

     Select Case mandat
        Case "x"
           lVal = 0
        Case "y"
           lVal = 1
     End Select

     strVal = CStr(lVal)
        folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "kfxpdf.exe")
     ElseIf Project.ScriptExecutionMode = CscScriptModeServer Then
        For i = 0 To folder.GetTotalDocumentCount - 1
           Set oXDocInfo = folder.GetDocInfoByGlobalIndex(i)
           oXDocInfo.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING", strVal)
           oXDocInfo.XDocument.NextValidationInstance = lVal
           oXDocInfo.XDocument.Valid = False
        Next
        ' validation is not done => rout to the depending validation instance
        If(lVal = 0) Then
           folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "KTM.Validation")
        Else
           folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DCOUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "KTM.Validation")
           folder.XValues.Set("KTM_DOCUMENTROUTING_QUEUE_" & strVal, "KTM.Validation" & CStr(lVal + 1))
           pXRootFolder.Valid = False
        End If
     End If
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an error per se but rather an informative message, telling you that the batch has no error, and that you might as well close the batch in Validation right away. Not having seen the project, this might be a stretch - but it would explain why you would see said message in the first instance of Validation. This is based on the assumption that you have no validation rules in your project, no fields set to require manual confirmation, thus all documents are valid at any time.

When opening a batch in Validation 1, none of your documents will have an error - consequentially, KTM makes the entire xfolder object valid. However, there is this single line in your code: `pXRootFolder.Valid = False` - meaning that you manually set the root folder invalid for all other instances of Validation.

To verify my hypothesis, simply set one of the fields to "manual confirmation required", or the valid property of your root folder to false - this should then result in Validation 1 showing a similar behavior to all other instances. In addition, when opening batches in Validation, take a close look at the folder (or batch if there is only one folder) symbol in the tree at the left-hand side of your screen - there should be a difference between Validation 1 and 2.

If you want to be absolutely sure, process two batch right before validation 1 and 2, but don't open them yet. Navigate to your server file share, typically `\\{Server}\CaptureSV\Images`, and copy the two most recent folders to any location. Open those folders in Project Builder (make sure to select the folder that holds your xfd file, or the folder object), and observe that one batch is valid while the other isn't (for example by testing validation in Project Builder, or F8).

Comment: thx, for your answer! but everytihing loking the same if i test it like you told me...

Comment: there are also fields that needs manual field confirmations so i dont unterstand why i see the message